# Notify users when their post is deleted or provide a way to view own deleted posts

Tags: feature-request

A week or so again I dug out an old problem that I had been working on and had sat on the back burner for a long time.  I thought I had posted a question on StackOverflow about it, but I looked through my history and didn't see it, so I wrote up a new question and was about to post it when I decided to search Google again as writing up the post gave me some ideas for other search terms.  When I did, to my surprise the first hit was my own original post, which had been deleted!

I'm not sure why the post was deleted, other than the fact that it had gone about a year (after posting before deletion) with no comments or answers, but it also had no down-votes, so I assume it was some routine "cleanup" that somebody had decided to do.  Nonetheless it was very annoying because I knew I had posted something but could not find it in my history which convinced me I was mistaken because I had no clue it might have been deleted.

Now as far as I can tell, there isn't any way I can search through posts of mine that have been deleted by others, so there isn't any way to prevent this from happening in the future, aside from perhaps going through all my old unsolved problems and copying them to my computer, which seems to defeat the purpose of having a central repository that I can't lose or forget where I put it.

I would like to propose a feature to prevent this from happening in the future: either let me see posts of my own which others have deleted, or else give me some sort of notification, so I don't go back a year later trying to create the exact same question.

Comment: You can *already* view your own deleted posts; there are links in the Questions and Answers tabs of your profile to 'recently deleted posts'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that only helps if the post is deleted in the last 30 (or 60?) days

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, that is good to know for newer posts.  But yes, as ChrisF says, that only goes back so far.  Apparently deleted posts are kept forever though, since Google still had it indexed and clicking on it still brought up the deleted post a year later.

Comment: @ChrisF: sure, but it satisfies most of the use cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - it may satisfy *most* of the use cases, but not all. If we don't emphasise the "recent" part of the option we'll get people complaining that they still can't see older deleted posts.

Comment: @ChrisF: tbh, I had not read far enough to see that the post had been deleted for a year now.

Comment: @Michael: do you have a link for us? Then at least we can tell you why it was deleted.

Comment: The world hasn't ended by letting people see 60 day old deleted posts as far as I've seen on meta. Why can't this be extended with a view to getting rid of the time limit entirely?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the link @MartijnPieters is referencing is "deleted recent posts", not "recently deleted posts".  So something will only appear if it was asked recently (within last 60 days) and deleted.

Comment: If we notify the bad question users, they'll complain though.

Comment: @ChrisF psubsee2003 is correct.  Its best parsed as "recent (deleted) posts" rather than "recent (deleted posts)".  A post that was deleted yesterday posted a year ago does not show up (because it is not a "recent post") IIRC.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the post was probably automatically cleaned up by the Community user, based on the original poster's description: 0 votes, no answers, no activity.

Comment: @Michael deleted posts are kept forever, but not in a state that's visible to the outside world. Google probably just hasn't updated its index for your question yet, which is why it would show up in search results. It probably shows up as a 404 for users who don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts from other users. Google should see a 404 too if its crawler ever decided to revisit the page.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a meta stackexhange question? These kind of features are network-wide, as opposed to site-by-site, right?

Comment: Let's have this!