# Isn't this answer link-only?

Tags: discussion, support, link-only-answers, specific-answer

I have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114768/1092711) several times:

> [Yes.][1]
>
> This isn't the only method for doing it, but this is probably the most
>   elegant method I've encountered.
>
> [Here's another one.][2]

But moderators keep declining it. I've used to think that link-only answers don't add value to SO. I see this answer as a clear link-only, am I wrong?

Comment: The post is 4 and half years old and has been upvoted 14 times, it clearly has been *useful* to some. You don't just delete posts that have been useful. You can instead edit the post to add the external information, summarised.

Comment: If you flag a post as Not An Answer, it is the *community* that decides on the fate of the post, except that if there are enough 'recommend deletion' votes on a post with a positive score the flag is escalated to the moderators, who then make the call to delete or not. If your flag was declined, then either the community or the moderators decided the post *can stay*. Don't re-flag in such cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what about guidance given in [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773) "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*..."

Comment: @gnat: it answers the question though. If you remove the markup, only the 'here's another one' part is entirely useless. The first two sentences still stand as an answer. A bad answer perhaps, but still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I find it hard to figure how "yes" could answer the question "how can I do it..." To avoid misunderstanding I've seen part of the question "Is this possible with CSS?" but frankly, "yes" in this case looks more like exploiting slippery wording of the asker... ["community should not be penalized for that answerer or asker's failing"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116360/165773)

Comment: @gnat: sure, it is a terrible answer without the markup, worthy of downvote oblivion. But I can see that a moderator, looking at it in isolation, would see the votes, would see the wording that looks like an answer, and decline the flag.

Comment: `flagged several times` is worrisome...

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. This is one my first contributions to SO, and it certainly doesn't meet the requirements of the site with respect to answers. The information may be useful, but it certainly isn't presented properly in any fashion.

Comment: @brasofilo [hmm..what's that definition again?](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins133991.html)

Comment: @JoelEtherton you're welcome; I commented primarily to clarify context of the recent edit to that answer

Comment: @gnat: [relevant discussion for "yes" answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263103/why-were-my-not-an-answer-flags-on-answers-that-consist-only-of-yes-declined)

Comment: @Shog9 while I agree that NAA for "yes" / "no" is [sort of a russian roulette](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269297/839601 "another case"), worth noting that in this particular case question was "how can I do it...", ie neither a [yes/no kind](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773) nor a [gimme linkz request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)

Answer (score 5):

When you flagged it, what action would you have us take?

Delete it?

No. It conveys useful information (both of those links work and the first one is Gold).

Edit it to include the code to solve the issue?

There are 16 moderators.  Why is the onus on the moderator to edit a post that you can edit?

So while you may be right that it a link-only answer (sigh), it doesn't meet any of the criteria for deletion, and even if it did meet a single criteria for deletion, its deletion would make Stack Overflow a worse place because we're deleting useful content.

The answer has been flagged five times.  I'm surprised that none of the people elected to improve the answer.

Here are the results of those flags:

```
Nov 8 '13 at 15:34    User 1    not an answer                       Disputed
Nov 10 '13 at 1:46    User 2    invalid flags                       Disputed
Jan 13 at 9:01        User 3    (custom) it is very low quality     Helpful
Sep 1 at 18:19        User 4    (custom) it is a link-only answer   Helpful
3 mins ago            User 5    not an answer                       Declined
```

I've anonymized who flagged it, as well as the moderators that handled it; (and there may or may not be five different flaggers), but this tells you the breakdown of how the flags were handled.

**Disputed** means that the community did not agree.

"**Helpful**" but the answer sticking around means that the moderators thought the flagger flagged in Good faith, but elected not to take any action.

"**Declined**" means the moderator believes either the user acted in Bad Faith, or there was not a reason to mark it "Helpful".

I've edited the answer to include the completed CSS needed to make the answer more powerful.

If you see an answer that has a lot of upvotes that is comprised of just a link, there are many things you can do, flagging it should be the last resort.

You can:

- Edit it
- Leave a comment for the author
- See if the answer's quality (or lack thereof) is a result of the question, and improve the question or vote to close it.
- Flag the answer

Flagging is the nuclear option. Flags only result in one of two outcomes:

- The content is deleted (bad if the links convey useful information)
- Nothing.

[Previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted/251693#251693), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271886/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268378/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267382/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266982/do-tools-and-libraries-constitute-helpful-link-only-answers/266987#266987), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252000/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251813/flagged-answer-and-declined-with-11-score/251817#251817), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275066/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188083/not-an-answer-flag-declined/188087#188087), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200382/not-an-answer-flag-disputed/200385#200385), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187111/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195276/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183658/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169140/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179292/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373/16587).

Comment: FWIW I considered editing this answer but couldn't figure how to make a sensible summary of the linked article; it seems to be beyond my subject matter expertise to do right. I didn't flag but can imagine  flaggers having this issue too

Comment: consider [edit]ing to clarify what exactly is "nuclear" about flagging and deletion, specifically when author is active at SO. My understanding is, answerers have an option to edit and flag to undelete, haven't they?

Comment: +1 - This deserves upvotes just for setting a good example, but also for (once again) clearly explaining the reasoning behind why we often decline NAA and VLQ flags. Editing a post into shape should always be the first reaction.

Comment: @gnat These are things you can universally do, independent of how 'active' or 'inactive' a user is.  Deleting an answer makes it immediately invisible to someone from Google. Google comprises a ton of traffic; it'd be unfair to delete good content because we don't like its form. It's far better (and less jarring) if we engage users to fix their content, or use our editing powers and do it ourselves. Also, [doesn't seem like deletions do well in the notification arena](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256160).

Comment: +1: I personally would have preferred that the "low-quality-ness" of the format of the answer be brought to my attention. Rather than simply flagging and moving on, pointing it out to the author might help them generate a better answer at that time.

Comment: @gnat: Totally understandable, but none of the comments to me actually ever mentioned the quality of the answer itself, nor was I notified of the flags. This is certainly something I would have made an effort to correct myself if I'd known of the issue then.

Comment: @JoelEtherton yeah that also stroke me as somewhat weird. Unless there are deleted comments (moderators can verify that), nobody of flaggers / moderators ever bothered to comment suggesting an edit; there aren't even auto-generated comments from review queue there. Weird; handling issues is so much easier [when there are comments](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uxtsB.png "example :)")

Comment: @gnat There were no comments asking to improve the quality of the answer and remove the _link-only?_ nature of it.  Also the last flag that would have gone into the VLQ was from 11/8/13 (NAA) and it was deemed invalid by a 10K user.  At that time, if I recall correctly, didn't go to the queue.

Comment: @bluefeet that's sad. I can to some extent understand lazy / inexperienced flaggers and reviewers who let it go that way but why it wasn't commented by two moderators who handled flags as helpful on `Jan 13` and `Sep 1` in George's log (unless the flags were somehow auto-resolved from the queue - but then, there would be auto-generated comments there?)

Comment: @gnat moderators leaving comments on a post in these situations is not feasible, given the amount of flags moderators handle and the amount of time we spend processing *just* flags.  The onus should be on the person flagging to engage with the poster.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Honestly, I think that's where he's implying that the comment should come. At the moment someone deemed it "flaggable", they should also have made a comment as to why so the person who answered may have an opportunity to improve it. This is almost as annoying as anonymous down-votes, but I think in many cases this comes more as a detriment to the site for not providing the opportunity to improve the quality right away.

Comment: George I can somehow understand this approach for declined flags. But for helpful ones it feels somewhat... incomplete. I mean, moderator _already_ invested their effort and verified that flag indicates an issue in the post; they see (do they?) that there are no comments helping author to see this; why not just fill the gap so to speak? @JoelEtherton FWIW I _primarily_ expect comment to be made by flagger; I only wonder why don't moderators fill the gap when they resolve flag as helpful and find that flagger didn't comment

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Also, thanks for the edit on that answer. Completely appropriate.

Comment: @gnat It takes more effort to decline a flag than it does to mark it as helpful and not do anything.  The "investment" for marking a flag helpful is less than anything else.  The issue is that people have gotten so used to flagging to solve issues they've forgotten how to do anything else.  We're trying to stem that tide, because flagging is an inherently destructive solution.  It's far better for everyone if flaggers take a step back and engage, edit, and if none of those work, *then flag*. That's the best solution there is.

Comment: @gnat: Reasonable, but perhaps a suggestion for a modification of the moderator interface is in order. I understand the viewpoint that the moderator is already doing work and shouldn't have to do more work, but at the same time not commenting does no one any good. Perhaps if the decline interface had an additional button or checkbox to insert an "auto-comment" similar to how the duplicate close vote inserts a comment and/or comment upvote.

Comment: @JoelEtherton We already have to give specific reasons for declining a flag. We can optionally include a comment; we can also optionally include comments for accepting flags -- but that's a more recent occurrence.  In both cases, the onus should be on the flagger to leave comments, not the moderator.  Would you rather put everything on the backs of 16 people? Or have the community take charge and do the work?  Thousands of people scale, 16 do not.

Comment: thanks for explanation George, I think I understand now how it went. Still feels somewhat weird but hopefully cases like this are rare enough to be dealt with through meta

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Oh, no, I'm not suggesting that. I'm just suggesting sort of an optional "stock" message (decline button, decline w/notice button) that dumps a "canned" note as a comment on the answer. "Your answer was flagged for quality, but a moderator chose to decline the flag. Please consider improving the quality of your answer if possible." I'm not indicating any suggestion that would add work to the moderators certainly.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: For the record, I haven't seen the interface or dealt with it, so I don't know if such a suggestion would be feasible or merely clutter in the interface. It's just a random idea that maybe one of the SO developers may or may not be able to use/run with.