# Link only answer flag declined. But why?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, link-only-answers

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905611/1927832), which more of looks like a link only answer:

> Followed [@pimvdb's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905611/1927832), and created my own:
>
> http://daniel-hug.github.io/characters/
>
> Be patient, as it takes 10-20 seconds to generate a table row for all 65536 characters that have a javascript keycode.

I didn't see any code, any logic behind generating the table etc.. Just a link (working now) and asking users to wait for few seconds to load/whatever which is again in the same link. I have a feeling that this is not an actual answer and more of link only answer. So I flagged it. Unfortunately it got declined with a message

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Coming to the question again, if a post have link alone, that is the only [valid link only answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Though the post I'm referring have some content, which is not at all discussing about the problem and just a request to users like *Be patient, the link will load little late*..

Comment: There is no link-only-answer flag. Only a no-answer flag. But this is an answer. maybe not a good one but still

Comment: @juergend There is no `link only answer` in the flagging reasons. So I flagged it as other and added a comment that `it is a link only answer`.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ [I'd suggest reading this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275584/isnt-this-answer-link-only/275586#275586)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ A post being a link only answer isn't a reason to flag it.  Many link only answers will happen to meet other criteria for flagging; if they do, flag them for that reason.  If they don't meet any of the criteria for flagging, then they shouldn't be flagging them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters dupe doesn't look accurate. It's rather the case where [_another castle_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773 "'when the question is kinda asking for bad answers...'") guidance suggests to look at the question instead, because as far as I can tell it asks for off-site resources: "Is there a full list of blah blah available?" Question looks worthy of closure and deletion (or maybe historical lock, given that it has over 70K views)

Comment: @gnat In what way is the post asking for off site resources?  It's asking for a list of codes.  One could certainly put that in an SO answer instead of linking to somewhere else that lists them.

Comment: @Servy Wouldn't that most likely be a very long answer? I would agree that maybe it's not asking for "offsite" resources, but it does seem like a very broad question to me. It just happens that the accepted answer points somewhere else.

Comment: @Kendra I didn't say it was a good question, just that it's not explicitly asking for link only answers, so the relevant quote gnat posted wouldn't apply.

Comment: @Servy word "available" makes it so. Editing it out, so that question becomes like "give me list (or how do I build a list) of blah blah" would make the not-a-resource-request magic, but this would also invalidate existing answer(s)

Comment: @Servy True, I misinterpreted your comment as "it probably shouldn't be closed." Apologies. But I do agree, probably not worthy of "off-site resources" closure.

Comment: @gnat "avaliable" in that context is referring to "what keycodes are available" not "what lists are already available".

Comment: @gnat "available" is really only in the title. The question itself makes no mention to if one is "available" or not, just that the OP wants one.

Comment: @Servy (upon re-reading the question) agree, "available" is probably not the culprit here. "Is there" poisons it, along with making it a [yes/no question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: @gnat That's trying *really* hard to warp the question, especially considering that the body of the question has none of those problems.  If it really bothers you just edit the title.

Comment: @Kendra we can try to drill into wording nuances until hell freezes over but other answers to the question indicate that readers perceive it (in its current form) as request for links: "Here is a complete list--I believe: <URL>", "Here are some useful links:<URL>...", "For a complete keyCode reference, see <URL>..."

Comment: @Servy see above ^^^

Comment: @gnat If users are incorrectly perceiving the question as asking for links when its not, all the more reason to edit the question to clarify it and avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Servy agree with that. Just note that such an edit would likely mean need to remove link-only answers, including the one asked about here (wonder if 70k views would justify aggressive mod involvement, ["Atwood maintenance"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) kind)

Comment: @gnat Given that the edit wouldn't be changing the question, merely preventing an incorrect perception, it's not the edit that would change anything.

Comment: @Servy in my experience, preventing an incorrect perception goes smoothly on early stages. Once question gains popular answers exploiting that incorrect perception, there's often pain and suffering

Comment: @gnat I won't argue with that point.