# Why is there no notification of your questions/answers being deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Why is there no notification procedure when questions and/or answers are deleted?

What is there to stop a high-reputation user from using the deletion feature to their advantage to exert power of those they don't like?

How are affected individuals even supposed to notice such deletions if the whole thing disappears from their profile without leaving any trace whatsoever?

Comment: If you had any sort of reputation change from the post, you do get notified via your reputation history. If you want more in-your-face deletion notifications, that's a feature request. The system is working as intended here.

Comment: `What is there to stop a high-reputation user from using the deletion feature to their advantage to exert power of those they don't like?` The fact that no high reputation users have unilateral deletion powers over posts that aren't their own...

Comment: The corresponding feature request can be found [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256160/2675154).

Comment: Related: [What, if anything, happens to questions with a negative score?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256019/)

Comment: `How are affected individuals even supposed to notice such deletions` They probably aren't - and after witnessing interactions with users for six years, I think that is very much by design to preserve everybody's sanity.

Answer (score 9):

When I inspect the question history in my profile page, there's a link to activate showing *deleted recent questions*, and you can actively track down deleted questions using this.

Regarding notifications, these are already sent, if some reputation change was triggered from deletion.

> What is there to stop a high-reputation user from using the deletion feature to their advantage to exert power of those they don't like?

High rep users cannot delete your question single handedly on their own; it needs two other (high rep) users to agree.

A designated moderator (check if there's a ♦ postfix at the name) of the site, can do this. Even without leaving you a comment about the reasoning.

Comment: Note that post need to have low enough score (like -2/-3?) for regular high-rep user to be able to vote for deletion. Regular users can't go and delete positively voted posts at all.

Comment: How many days is "recent"?  What if I want to track down an older post?

Comment: @NisseEngström IIRC it's 60 days.